# Using variables within quoted strings in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja

Please take this working play example:

```
- name: Display the URL
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - host_domain: "testing.example.com"
    - default_url: "http://def.localhost.{{ host_domain }}"
    - my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default(default_url) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_url }}"
```

This works fine. The output is as expected:

```
msg: http://def.localhost.testing.example.com
```

I would like to set the default value in-line, without first declaring the `default_url` var. Something like this:

```
  vars:
    - host_domain: "testing.example.com"
    - my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.{{ host_domain }}') }}"
```

I've tried different techniques:

- `my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default(\'http://def.localhost.{{ host_domain }}\') }}"`
- `my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default(\"http://def.localhost.{{ host_domain }}\") }}"`
- `my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.'{{ host_domain }}) }}"`
- `my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.'host_domain) }}"`

I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never nest `{{...}}` template markers. Inside a Jinja template context, just use regular Jinja syntax for referring to variables. See [the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) for details.

So, instead of:

```
  vars:
    - host_domain: "testing.example.com"
    - my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.{{ host_domain }}') }}"
```

You would write:

```
  vars:
    - host_domain: "testing.example.com"
    - my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.{}'.format(host_domain)) }}"
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - host_domain: "testing.example.com"
    - my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.{}'.format(host_domain)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_url }}"
```

This outputs:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "http://def.localhost.testing.example.com"
}
```

You could also write `default('http://def.localhost.%s' % (host_domain))` (using `%`-style formatting), or `default('http://def.localhost.' ~ host_domain)` (using the string concatenation operator).

Answer (score 3):

this works:

`my_url: "{{ some_undeclared_var | default('http://def.localhost.' + host_domain) }}"`

(concatenate strings)